# How to pick words, start and end with specific words using shell script in a log file

Tags: shell

I am tring to pick words start with "Approved by" and end with before the "=" sign. here is log file.

```
Test worker] INFO cyyom.bghhht.gsghhj.dijjkkgital.dggcf.applicationservice.service.RequestServiceImpl - Approved List : 
[AssignAccountApplicationRequestDto [status=true, requestId=1, backendData=BackendPopupDto [userID=0, companyId=0, ApplicationId=0, 
userType=Test, corpId=0, revenueOwner=notnull, requestedDate=null]]] , Rejected List : [AssignAccountApplicationRequestDto [status=false, requestId=11, backendData=null]]
Approved by ha:////4P4ei7QWIY1VDT3ygY1geg0Q82Jj2AqLzGAAAAmh+LCAAAAAAAAP9b85aBtbiIQTGjNKU4P08vOT+vOD8nVc83PyU1x6OyILUoJzMv2y+/
JJUBAhiZGBgqihhk0NSjKDWzXb3RdlLBUSYGJk8GtpzUvPSSDB8G5tKinBIGIZ+sxLJE/ZzEvHT94JKizLx0a6BxUmjGOUNodHsLgAyxEgY+/
dLi1CL99OKCxJTczDwAUT2GdsMAAAA=PSPortal Administrator
```

I tried

```
awk '$1 == "Approved" { print $3, $4 }' log
```

then result was

```
ha:////4P4ei7QWIY1VDT3ygY1geg0Q82Jj2AqLzGAAAAmh+LCAAAAAAAAP9b85aBtbiIQTGjNKU4P08vOT+vOD8nVc83PyU1x6OyILUoJzMv2y+/JJUBAhiZGBgqihhk0NSjKDWzXb3RdlLBUSYGJk8GtpzUvPSSDB8G5tKinBIGIZ+sxLJE/ZzEvHT94JKizLx0a6BxUmjGOUNodHsLgAyxEgY+/dLi1CL99OKCxJTczDwAUT2GdsMAAAA=PSPortal Administrator
```

expected output

```
PSPortal Administrator
```

Comment: I can't see `PSPortal ` in your actual shown sample file, please do update it to make question more clear, thank you.

Comment: Thanks for mention it. I added the missing lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code. Considering that line starts with `Approved by` and `=` comes in same line then do following.

```
awk -F'=' '/^Approved by / && NF>=2{print $NF}'  Input_file
```

***OR*** if you have only one `=` in line then try following:

```
awk -F'=' '/^Approved by / && NF==2{print $NF}'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be, setting field separator as `=` for all lines of Input_file. In main program checking condition if line starts from `Approved by`  and `NF` is equal to 2 then print last field of that line.

Comment: thank you so much. It worked. If it is possible can you tell me a way to learn these awk commands. Could you recommend any source for it

Comment: @Zero5, sure. for learning `awk` check this link https://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/info

Comment: Hi I need to change the output of awk script.
Condition needed to check is starts with 'Approved by' and ends with after 'AAAA'
new output should be "=PSPortal Administrator". feel free cloud you assist me